# PowerShell Add-DistributionGroupMember - Error failed because it's out of the current user's write scope

Tags: powershell, distribution-list

I am the owner for one of the Distribution group and i am able to add/remove members in Exchange Admin Center (EAC). However, I am getting an error while adding members using the cmd

"Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "DL Group Name" -Member 'MemberID' ".

Error Message: failed because it's out of the current user's write scope.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prkZx.png)

I am able to get the members present in the DL, but its not allowing me add the member via PowerShell.

Any additional permissions required for Add-DistributionGroupMember ?

Answer (score 0):

The object is synced from on-premises, you need to run the command against your on-premises Exchange Server not Exchange Online.